# How to make search results include subdocument using .find() in Node js with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Good Day,
For context, I am using node js, express and MongoDB in my project.
I have this code:

```
router.get('/test3', async (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    // eslint-disable-next-line dot-notation
    const to = cookies['to'];
    console.log.apply(to);

    SearchDb.findOne({"to": to}, (err, item) => {

        console.log(item);
    });

    res.json("see cnsole");
});
```

and it returns something like this on the terminal

```
School

{
 _id: new ObjectId("619be4e74c6a2504334f4a4d"),
 from: 'Home',
 to: 'School',
 step: [
   {
     _id: new ObjectId("61a733c0a7614d6ba7f91561"),
     start: 'Home',
     vehicle: 'Taxi',
     end: 'School',
     cost: 100,
     ave_time: 20
   }
 ]
}
```

However, I don't really want to use .findOne(), I want to use .find() in case there are multiple search results, when I replace .findOne with .find() though, this is what shows on the terminal

```
School

{
 _id: new ObjectId("619be4e74c6a2504334f4a4d"),
 from: 'Home',
 to: 'School',
 step: [ [Object] ]
}
```

The subdocument "step" now returns [ [Object] ], which makes it hard to do things like item.step.length since it will now return undefined.

What should be done to make .find() show the whole document including the subdocuments just like .findOne?

Answer (score 0):

[@Bsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17496704/bsn) try this here I'm sending your result on front try POSTMAN for get or browser in console you are getting [object] but in your actual result you will get whole array of an object :)

```
router.get("/test3", async (req, res) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  // eslint-disable-next-line dot-notation
  const to = cookies["to"];
  console.log.apply(to);

  try {
    SearchDb.find((err, item) => {
      res.json(item);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
  }
});
```